# How to upgrade an Arch Linux system after downgrading some packages?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

After using `pacman` to upgrade my system, the AUR package QGIS broke (the program wouldn't open; plenty of others had issues as well). To fix this, I intentionally downgraded several packages via the fix [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qgis/). This got QGIS working so I was happy. But now when I use `pacman -Syu` to update my system I get

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: qgis: installing qscintilla-qt4 (2.10-1) breaks dependency 'qscintilla-qt4<2.10'
:: qgis: installing python2-qscintilla-qt4 (2.10-1) breaks dependency 'python2-qscintilla-qt4<2.10'
:: qgis: installing python-qscintilla-qt4-common (2.10-1) breaks dependency 'python-qscintilla-qt4-common<2.10'
```

And nothing updates. Clearly, my manual downgrading of packages for the sake of QGIS is the culprit here. Is there a way to do a system upgrade on all *but* these packages so that QGIS continues to work? Or is this bad practice? Should I just use QGIS in a virtual machine or something instead?

The specific package in question (QGIS) is not so concerning to me. I am more curious about how to deal with `pacman` in these instances.

Comment: [Partial upgrades are not supported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported). The correct approach is for the AUR maintainer to update *their* package so it builds against an up-to-date system.

Answer (score 2):

Does IgnorePkg work for you? e.g

```
IgnorePkg=qgis
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Skip_package_from_being_upgraded

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work. Admittedly, I didn't try that hard. I decided to just remove QGIS and I'll run in it a VM if I need it.